# Retornar height min-height max-height con función SASS SCSS

Tags: css, scss

Tengo esta función:

```
@function minmaxwh($pxx,$tipo){
  #{$tipo} : #{$pxx}px;
  max-#{$tipo} : #{$pxx}px;
  min-#{$tipo} : #{$pxx}px;
}
```

Y lo que deseo es que yo al poner `minmaxwh(34,height);`
Me muestre:

```
height:34px;
min-height:34px;
max-height:34px;
```

En donde height es el segundo parámetro ($tipo: width o height) y 34 es el primer parámetro ($pxx)

Comment: ¿Por qué en lugar de una función no utilizás un mixin, como muestra en la [documentación](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#interpolation)?

Comment: me parecio mejor idea insertarlo asi: minmaxwh(...) que @include mimaxwh(...)

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Para eso necesitas que se interprete la variable $tipo como una cadena, por lo que cuando llames a la función, debería ser algo así:

```
 minmaxwh(34, 'height');
```

Es decir, tienes que pasarle el tipo entre comillas